# Difference between de, desde, and a partir de (prepositions)

Tags: diferencias-regionales

I'm really new to the Spanish language and I'm trying to get a good understanding of these prepositions. I was taught that:

De = of,from

Desde = since,from

But then i found out that:

a partir de = from

How would i know which one to use if i needed to use 'from' in spanish???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are new to Spanish, you shouldn't be troubling yourself to understand what you think to be anomalies.  Each of those words/phrases has it's own purpose in the language, it's not like you just pick one and use it.

Yes, they all mean `from`.  But even in English, there are different variations of `from`.

```
 Since, Starting at, Originating, Deriving, Materializing, Dematerializing
```

`Desde` is used to introduce, indicate and designate a starting point in your sentence, and always in the past.

```
 Desde el día que llegué aquí comía muchos legumbres.
 Since the day I arrived here I ate a lot of vegetables.

 Mi padre me dió una cerveza cuándo era niño y desde entonces yo era alcohólico.
 My dad gave me a beer when I was a child and since then I have been an alcoholic.
```

`A partir de` does the same thing but it's more flexible.  This preposition allow you to set your starting point in the future.

```
 A partir de la próxima semana empezaré a hacer ejercicio.
 Starting next week I will start exercising.

 A partir de que llegue Pablo prepararé la cena.
 As soon as Pablo arrives, I will prepare dinner.

 Se explotará una burbuja a partir de que se la toque.
 A bubble will explode as soon as it is touched.
```

Answer (score 1):

*De* is a genetic preposition that occasionally needs clarification. If you're using it to mean *from* (as in starting at), the clarifying preposition is *desde*. Curiously, whether you course *de* or *desde* will dictate which word you use for the end of range: *de X a Y* but *desde X hasta Y*.

*A partir de* is often used with time or quantities, and is used to say *starting at* (or *after/beyond*). It usually is only used as establishing the lower limit on a range with no established upper range.